# Fund an address and send a tx in a single block

Tags: gas, mining, nodes

Take the following situation

- `0xb...` doesn't have any ethereum
- `0xa...` send ethereum to `0xb...` on block `x` with gas price `y+1`
- `0xb...` make a transaction with a smart contract on block `x` with gas price `y`

Theorically, this would work in most cases, as 99% of miners do mine transactions by gas prices. So `0xb...` would have enough ethereum to pay for gas by the time the miner get to his transaction.

However, in my experience, nodes won't accept to relay a tx if the address doesn't have enough ethereum to pay for gas at the time the tx is broadcasted.

Is there a way to circuvant this and be able to both fund and send a transaction from an address in a single block ?

Comment: Check the flashbots project, they have some tools to group transactions.